# Consuming OData v4 services in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, odata

I'm looking for nice alternatives for consuming OData V4 services in .NET Core.

What are the alternatives? The Microsoft.OData.Client doesn't have support yet as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. OData client supports .Net core since the version [7.4.0-beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client/7.4.0-beta).